# NSAttributedString - textview not showing attributed text after segue

Tags: swift, segue, xcode7

I have a problem with segues or my textview.
There are two view controllers: ViewController and TextViewController. Both view controllers are showing a UITextView and a button.
I've created a segue called "textSegue" when I press the "Text" button on the ViewController the text is passed to the TextViewController and displayed. On the TextViewController I can select the text and press the "Bold" button to make the text bold. When I press the "Back" button, the TextViewController is dismissed and the ViewController will show the attributed text.
The problem is, when I press the "Text" button again and the TextViewController shows, the text in the UITextView doesn't show the attributed text (it is'n bold anymore).

I think the segue did pass the attributed text properly, but somehow the textview doesn't show it properly. Is there anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong?

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, TextViewControllerDelegate {

    var newtext = NSAttributedString()
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    @IBAction func btnText(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("textSegue", sender: nil)
        newtext = textView.attributedText
        print("viewcontroller btnText pressed")
        print("newtext :", newtext)
    }

    @IBAction func btnLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newtext = textView.attributedText
        print("ViewController ViewDidLoad")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "textSegue"{
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! TextViewController
            vc.myString = newtext
            vc.delegate = self
            print("open Textview:")
            print(newtext)
        }
    }

    func setText(controller: TextViewController, nieuwetext: NSAttributedString) {
        newtext = nieuwetext
        print("Segue ontvangen1: ", newtext)
        textView.attributedText = newtext
        controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
```

TextViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol TextViewControllerDelegate {
    func setText(controller: TextViewController, nieuwetext: NSAttributedString);
}

class TextViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : TextViewControllerDelegate! = nil
    var myString = NSAttributedString(string: "")

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func btnTextBack(sender: AnyObject) {
        myString = textView.attributedText
        print("textview btnTextBack pressed: ")
        print(myString)
        if (delegate != nil) {
            delegate!.setText(self, nieuwetext: myString)
        }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

    }
    @IBAction func btnBold(sender: AnyObject) {
        textView.toggleBoldface(self)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.attributedText = myString
        print("textView viewDidLoad")
        print("myString: ", myString)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid its a bug :( can anyone verify this? Or prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added

```
textView.attributedText = myString
```

to ViewDidAppear (so now its in ViewDidAppear and ViewDidLoad). In ViewDidLoad it doesn't seem to load the attributes, but in ViewDidAppear it does.

a bug perhaps?